# When i have 2 or more material on my object it turns black

Tags: modeling, mesh, texturing, materials, uv

When i have 2 or more material on my object it turns black.

[image: y]

This black thing is showing and I don't know why. please anyone?

Comment: please edit your question and add images that show the node trees of the materials you are dealing with, and how you are combining them.

Comment: have you imported it? maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: It's very hard to tell without seeing your nodes, but given both your materials contain the word "mask" I'm assuming there is some transparency involved. Make sure the alpha from your texture is connected to the alpha input of the BSDF, then down in the material properties under "Blend Mode", choose alpha blend, clip, or hashed - just not opaque.